# How can I not fail hard at QWOP?

Tags: qwop

I'm trying to beat the epic struggle that is [QWOP](http://www.foddy.net/Athletics.html), but I clearly haven't mastered it. I've been able to get to the first hurdle at 50m by essentially scraping my knee the entire time, but my strategy breaks down when trying to get past it:

[image: A truly epic QWOP failure]

Is there an ideal key sequence to generate the intended/proper running form so that I may find out what magical things lie in wait beyond?

Comment: When you master QWOP, you can try GIRP: http://www.foddy.net/GIRP.html

Comment: i don't want to get better at qwop.  qwop's the game i play when i need more laughter and stomach pain in my life.

Comment: GIRP is easier than QWOP in my opinion.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Tap <kbd>O</kbd> at the beginning to lean forward a little

After that, you use <kbd>W</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>Q</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> alternately take your strides. Make sure you stay leaning slightly forward. Don't wait until your front foot hits the ground before you take your next stride; push off a little earlier.

Be prepared to fail many, many times.

Comment: Don't worry, everyone is a winner!

Answer (score 8):

An alternate method that some people use to get far is basically falling to their knees and only using <kbd>Q</kbd> and <kbd>W</kbd> (thighs) and dragging themselves along. This really only gives me a good excuse to post this inspirational video.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of hitting <kbd>w</kbd> and <kbd>o</kbd> at the same time, hit them in really quick succession.  It works a lot better and you can run faster.

Answer (score 0):

First press W and O at the same time on your keyboard. Then, for the next step press Q and P at the same time. Keep alternating these for each step.

It takes practice to get used to the timing (when and for how long to press the keys). It worked fine for me while [playing QWOP unblocked](http://www.unblockedgamesroom.com/qwop) and i did 100.2 as final result

Comment: Ooh, interesting website...